# How do I detect if an object is a Waterline model or model collection in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I need to traverse the tree of objects. Some objects are Waterline models or model collections, that I need to treat in a specific way. So, how do I reliably detect if a JavaScript object is a Waterline model or collection in Sails.js?

Answer (score 0):

here's a snippet. in my model toJSON() call i need to know if i'm passing in a model or a json object. so i just check for the associations property.

```
    toJSON: function(users) {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        var arr = _.map(users, function(user) {
            if (user.hasOwnProperty('associations')) {
                return user.toJSON();
            }
            else {
                return user;
            }
        });
        obj.users = arr;
        return obj;
    }
```